# Windows Forms color variation between Windows 7 and XP

Tags: windows, forms, windows-7, colors, windows-xp

I have a vb.net Windows Forms app using the 4.0 framework.   When I run the application on an XP machine, the color of my controls all match what the are set to in my IDE, which is also an XP machine.

When I run this application on a  Windows 7 machine, the colors are all changed.

Any ideas why this is and how I can make Windows 7 match my Development machine?

David

Answer (score 2):

Windows forms are going to take on whatever "theme" the machine they are running on has enabled - which is by design. Honestly, it wouldn't make sense for a windows form running on Windows 7 to look like an XP windows form. Could you give some sort of context for why you want your windows form to look like it's always running on XP?

Comment: Back colors are all changed from "Control" to black, text changed from "black" to blue.  Makes the form almost unusable. I don't care if it looks like XP, I just want it to match the colors I choose in the IDE.

Comment: It shouldn't act like that on Windows 7. I would go through the elements of your control in the designer .cs file and make sure you aren't setting the color of something to a non-default value. If all the colors are set a "System" color, it should be completely usable and match the system theme on all versions of windows that support .NET 4.0.

Comment: I've since tried tweaking the themes to no effect.  Nor do I change any colors in my program.  There are no custom controls, pretty much straight out of the box VS 2010 windows forms.  The behavior is very consistent between several XP and Win7 machines.

Comment: Hold the phones... Looks like the themes are the culprit.  I selected "Windows Classic" theme in the Windows 7 and the colors all matched.  Sure wish I could preserve my colors regardless of the theme...

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the UseVisualStyleBackColor to False?

Comment: That's interesting Johnie, but my controls don't have that property.  But the buttons do.  Might be a clue though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include that in my comment here.  I modified my answer to be more specific to what I was talking about.  When I tried UseVisualStyleBackColor (false) on my buttons it used the colors I chose.  When true it used the OS theme.

Comment: In the back color properties, you have the choice of Custom, Web, or System.   If you use a system color it appears to reference the Theme.  Using custom, the color stays the same.  Newbie problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BackColor property of the button to change the background color.  The ForeColor property will change the text color.

Edit: added the below after playing around some.

Try ensuring the "UseVisualStyleBackColor" property on your button is set to False.  Playing around I noticed that when this is true, the system ignores my background color selection and uses the machine default.  When False, my background color was used.

Comment: Thanks Johnie, but the colors selected by in the properties of the control are overridden by the theme that the PC is using.  Not an XP or Win7 issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this too. My VB6 project was fine in Windows XP.
I just moved to Windows 7 and copied the project folder to this machine.
My splashscreen backcolour was supposed to be white but it was black now.
The backcolour had been set to &H80000009& which was white in winXP but in Windows 7 it gives black.
So I changed backcolour to &H80000005& and it is now white again.