# Windows Forms Application - Visual Style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible.

A button created in a Windows Forms Application looks like this:

[image]

If I create a form manually, buttons I create will look like this:

[image]

I looked thoroughly through the Windows Forms Application and found no code that changes the visual style of buttons.

Is there any simple explanation as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you create the form manually?

Comment: Maybe it is helpful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Also take a look at this post, there is a lot of helpful information in the various comments.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127597/windows-forms-color-variation-between-windows-7-and-xp/

Comment: @DavidePiras I meant, I created a Form in a project that is not a "Windows Forms Application".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to call the [`EnableVisualStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx) method, which is by default called in the `Main` method of the `Program` class prior to calling `Application.Run` (when you create a Windows Forms project, with the auto-generated code).

> This method enables visual styles for the application. Visual styles
>   are the colors, fonts, and other visual elements that form an
>   operating system theme. Controls will draw with visual styles if the
>   control and the operating system support it. To have an effect,
>   `EnableVisualStyles()` must be called before creating any controls in
>   the application; typically, `EnableVisualStyles()` is the first line in
>   the Main function. A separate manifest is not required to enable
>   visual styles when calling `EnableVisualStyles()`.

Comment: Somehow, I overlooked this... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you set the buttons `UseVisualStyleBackColor` to `true` and that you call `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in your startup code.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmAddress());
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Effect of UseVisualStyleBackColor:

[image]

Comment: `EnableVisualStyles` is indeed what I was looking for, but the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` property of buttons doesn't seem to make any difference for me.

Comment: On my Win7 `UseVisualStyleBackColor = true` lets my buttons look a bit like horizontal cylinders. Otherwise they have the Win XP look, but look more or less flat (the difference is small).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have Visual Styles enabled (the default), part of the display of the button is controlled by the Operating System, outside the control of your program. The same program running on Windows 7 with the standard interface will look different than when it's running in classic mode.

Bold emphasis added to the excerpt from the documentaiton to illustrate this point.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6kzhf8d(VS.80).aspx

> Windows XP introduced a new look and feel to the Windows user
>   interface, with controls that have rounded corners and that change
>   color when you pause your mouse over them. By default, Windows-based
>   applications created with Visual Basic automatically support visual
>   styles, also known as Windows XP Themes. **When run on a platform that
>   does not support Windows XP Themes, the application reverts to the
>   traditional Windows look and feel.**   If you do not want your
>   application to support visual styles, you can change the property on
>   the Application page of the Project Designer.

Also from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171733(VS.80).aspx

in the **Checking for Visual Styles Support** section.

the following conditions must be true for the visual styles to work:

- The operating system supports visual styles.
- The user has enabled visual styles in the operating system.
- Visual styles are enabled in the application.
- Visual styles are being used to draw the client area of application windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Untill before VS 2010, creating a custom manifest file did the job. However from Visual Studio 2010, this does not work, because VS creates a new file named app.manifest, inside the folder My Project.
So, to enable visual styles all you have to do is to edit this file from withing your project in Visual Studio and uncomment the lines bellow

```
<!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
```