# give custom style to c# windows application

Tags: c#, css, winforms

I am wondering if there is a way to customize style of windows forms application built in visual studio using c#. I have searched through the internet and couldn't find simple solution for overriding default view of the layout. Is there a way to change layout with cascading style sheets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WPF technology will let you do it and many more things relating to GUI styling issues. WinForms technology is rooted in old Windows GUI so you will spend many many more time to achieve the same effect as in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Forms apps do not support `CSS`, it is used when developing websites.

In Winforms you are limited to the styles which are listed in *Properties window* in GUI editor, unless you'd like to override `OnPaint` event and do custom drawing.

Some examples are:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8056/Creating-Custom-Shaped-Windows-Forms-in-NET

http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/07/04/CustomBorderForms.aspx

https://customerborderform.codeplex.com/

If you are looking for more customizable solution, you can turn to WPF.

Comment: I have a project in visual studio and it looks standard application. if i use the library u told me, i will have to change every button and form one by one. it would be better if there is a way to give style and once it is given, it would be applied to all buttons and forms. Appreciation anyway!

Comment: Which library are you referring to?

Comment: The best choice in case you want to have customizable interface is definitely WPF, but it will require you to withdraw your Winforms project and start from scratch.

Comment: Yes, i understood. But the thing is the project is almost finished and is about to be implemented. I will take into consideration what you have told. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[you can find answer here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244470/windows-forms-application-visual-style)

or

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static resource such as this.

Inside button tag Style="{DynamicResource sty3dBtn}"
(You can set margins here too but sometimes thats best to do for each button depending on your own needs)

You can use xml styling. The button is set to have a dropshadow and gradient and lights up when pressed etc. As I wanted to reuse these effects with similar buttons I created a reusable style in my Application.xaml enclosed in Application - Application.Resources tags
and referenced its x:Key in style attribute of the button I wanted the effect on. You can do this on each page you choose but I think it can be better to place in a common area so its reusable throughout the scope of the class you place it in. Note the Target Type must match.

I'll post snippet of the xml style it turns a regular button into one with 3d effect. You can reference this as many times as you need. It cuts down on inline code clutter too so makes the page more readable in my opinion.

```
    <Style x:Key="sty3dBtn" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="GelBackground" Opacity="1" RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"
                               Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="0.35"
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="YellowGreen" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="GelShine" Margin="2,2,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Opacity="1" Stroke="Transparent" Height="15px">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown">
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GelBackground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="GelBackground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GelBackground" Value="LightGray">

                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!-- Contains animation code-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="55"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the WinForms platform itself doesn't support CSS styles, you can use DevExpress components and their [HTML & CSS](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/403397/common-features/html-css-based-desktop-ui) feature for flexible UI customization